# To fix an item duplication glitch, I created an item deletion glitch

Tags: gui, godot-3, inventory

- The item type is based on `button.icon.texture`
- The item quantity is based on `button.quantity`
- If item quantity reaches 0, the `icon.texture` is set to empty.png. There's also the option to set it to null, so I made an elif statment just in case I need to use null.

The problem:

When adding items of the same type together, they stack, which is good. But when adding items of different types, they swap. Technically only the texture swaps, the quantities don't... the quantity is zeroed out and thus the texture is set to empty.png.

Removing this:

```
elif quantity == 0:
        quantity_label.text = ""
        icon.texture = preload("res://UI/graphics/SkillIcons/empty.png")
        print("zeroed out")
```

shows that in fact the textures are being swapped correctly, but the quantity isn't.

```
extends TextureButton
    
var DRAG_PREVIEW = preload("res://Sprite.tscn")
onready var icon = $Icon
onready var quantity_label = $Quantity

var quantity = rand_range(0, 25)
var item = "null"

func _ready():
    displayQuantity()
    matchItemTypeToIcon()

func _physics_process(delta):
    displayQuantity()

func displayQuantity():
    if quantity != 0: 
        quantity_label.text = str(round(quantity))
    elif quantity == 0:
        quantity_label.text = ""
        icon.texture = preload("res://UI/graphics/SkillIcons/empty.png")
        print("zeroed out")

func get_drag_data(position: Vector2):
    matchItemTypeToIcon()
    
    var slot = get_parent().get_name()
    var data = {
        "origin_node": self,
        "origin_slot": slot,
        "origin_texture": icon.texture,
        "origin_quantity": quantity,
        "origin_item": item
    }
    var dragPreview = DRAG_PREVIEW.instance()
    dragPreview.texture = icon.texture
    add_child(dragPreview)

    # Remove the icon from its original place
    icon.texture = preload("res://UI/graphics/SkillIcons/empty.png")
    quantity = 0
    displayQuantity()
    print("Item type:", item)
    return data

func can_drop_data(position, data):
    matchItemTypeToIcon()
    var target_slot = get_parent().get_name()
    data["target_texture"] = icon.texture
    data["target_quantity"] = quantity
    data["target_item"] = item
    return true

func drop_data(position, data):
    matchItemTypeToIcon()
    displayQuantity()
    var origin_texture = data["origin_texture"]
    var target_texture = icon.texture
    var origin_item = data["origin_item"]
    var target_item = item
    var origin_quantity = data["origin_quantity"]
    var target_quantity = quantity

    data["origin_node"].get_node("Icon").texture = target_texture
    icon.texture = origin_texture

    if origin_item == target_item:
        # Only combine the quantities if target_texture and origin_texture are the same
        quantity += data["origin_quantity"]
        
        data["origin_node"].get_node("Icon").texture = preload("res://UI/graphics/SkillIcons/empty.png")
    else:
        # Swap the quantities if the textures are different
        quantity = origin_quantity
        data["origin_quantity"] = target_quantity

func matchItemTypeToIcon():
    var icon_texture = icon.texture
    if icon_texture == preload("res://UI/graphics/mushrooms/PNG/background/1.png"):
        item = "mushroom 1"
    elif icon_texture == preload("res://UI/graphics/mushrooms/PNG/background/2.png"):
        item = "mushroom 2"
    elif icon_texture == null:
        item = "empty"
    elif icon_texture == preload("res://UI/graphics/SkillIcons/empty.png"):
        item = "empty"
    else:
        # Default item type if the texture doesn't match known types
        item = "unknown"
```

Comment: What stands out to me is that you are modifying the data on `can_drop_data`.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, but before it turns into something unpleasant, you should know that `var item = "null"` doesn't set `item` to `null`, it sets it to a string with that spells the word "null". Programmatically, those are not the same thing.

Comment: the only place `quantity` ever gets set to 0 seems to be in `get_drag_data`

Answer (score 0):

fixed the problem by storing quantities in a temporary variable at temp_quantity

here's the full edited script

```
 extends TextureButton

var DRAG_PREVIEW = preload("res://Sprite.tscn")
onready var icon = $Icon
onready var quantity_label = $Quantity

var quantity = rand_range(0, 25)
var item = "null"
var type = "item"
func _ready():
    displayQuantity()
    matchItemTypeToIcon()

func _physics_process(delta):
    displayQuantity()


func displayQuantity():
    if quantity != 0: 
        quantity_label.text = str(round(quantity))
    elif quantity == 0:
        quantity_label.text = ""
        icon.texture = null
        print("zeroed out")
    
    if icon.texture == null:
        quantity = 0
        quantity_label.text = ""

func get_drag_data(position: Vector2):
    matchItemTypeToIcon()
    
    var slot = get_parent().get_name()
    var data = {
        "origin_node": self,
        "origin_slot": slot,
        "origin_texture": icon.texture,
        "origin_quantity": quantity,
        "origin_item": item,
        "type": type
    }
    var dragPreview = DRAG_PREVIEW.instance()
    dragPreview.texture = icon.texture
    add_child(dragPreview)

    # Remove the icon from its original place
    #icon.texture = null
    #quantity = 0
    displayQuantity()
    print("Item type:", item)
    return data

func can_drop_data(position, data):
    matchItemTypeToIcon()
    displayQuantity()
    var target_slot = get_parent().get_name()
    data["target_texture"] = icon.texture
    data["target_quantity"] = quantity
    data["target_item"] = item
    if data["type"] != "skill":
        return true
    else:
        return false


func drop_data(position, data):
    matchItemTypeToIcon()
    displayQuantity()
    var origin_texture = data["origin_texture"]
    var target_texture = icon.texture
    var origin_item = data["origin_item"]
    var target_item = item
    var origin_quantity = data["origin_quantity"]
    var target_quantity = quantity
    var origin_node = data["origin_node"]
    var origin_icon = origin_node.get_node("Icon")

    origin_icon.texture = target_texture
    icon.texture = origin_texture

    if origin_item == target_item:
        # Combine quantities if items are the same
        quantity += data["origin_quantity"]
        origin_node.quantity = 0  # Reset the origin quantity
    else:
        # Swap quantities if items are different
        var temp_quantity = quantity
        quantity = origin_quantity
        origin_node.quantity = temp_quantity

    # Update the display
    displayQuantity()

func matchItemTypeToIcon():
    var texture_to_item = {
        preload("res://UI/graphics/mushrooms/PNG/background/1.png"): "mushroom 1",
        preload("res://UI/graphics/mushrooms/PNG/background/2.png"): "mushroom 2",
        preload("res://UI/graphics/SkillIcons/empty.png"): "empty"
    }
    
    if icon.texture in texture_to_item:
        item = texture_to_item[icon.texture]
    elif icon.texture == null:
        item = "empty"
    else:
        item = "unknown"
```

The entire system is based off godot's **built in** drag and drop functionaly, better explained in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaAqhIC5DaI&ab_channel=Artindi